# Android Studio BackgroundService run whole time without user interaction?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-service, background-service

I am having the problem that I want to have a BackgroundService in Android Studio which every few minuten runs and checks if a JSON File is changed.
My question is how to let the service run the whole time e. g. in standby, after boot & after the app started. I mean, how does WhatsApp or other messaging apps run their tasks the whole time?

Comment: "how does WhatsApp or other messaging apps run their tasks the whole time?" -- generally, they do not do that. They use Firebase Cloud Messaging, most likely. "My question is how to let the service run the whole time" -- use a foreground service, and bear in mind that your ability to do certain types of work will be limited while the device is in Doze mode.

Comment: JobScheduler can be used to run Task/Service every X time. Whatsapp and others Apps uses this. There are many questions/threads here in Stackoverflow about it.

Answer (score 1):

Polling and Pulling are highly discouraged in Android. There's no way which you can keep an Android device constantly checking for changes reliably (don't try it won't work on production with a variety of devices from different manufacturers).

Instead, take the checking part to the server-side and send a push whenever a change occurs. And to make things complicated, that push might also not receive to the device under certain conditions like Doze or App Standby modes.

Always test your application with [Doze and App Standby](https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby#testing_doze_and_app_standby) before shipping.